# How to use `ElButton` as a link using Element Plus and Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, element-plus

I'm using Element Plus 2.2.28 and Vue.js 3.2.45.

I want to have a button like this:

```
<el-button>Contact</el-button>
```

When I click the button, I want it to behave like a link tag using `mailto:someone@example.com`.

I tried this:

```
<el-button href="mailto:someone@example.com">Contact</el-button>
```

However, this doesn't work.

I could use pure JS in the `@click` event of the button, but I understand this is not recommended.

Comment: Maybe you can put a link tag inside the button, like `<el-button><a href="mailto:someone@example.com">Contact</a></el-button>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to click on the button to redirect you, then you do not need any other functionality that the el-button offers. As such, you only want the appearance of an el-button. Therefore, you can use the `el-button` class instead on an anchor tag as follows;

```
<a class="el-button" href="mailto:someone@example.com">Contact</a>
```